# Change selected value in combobox through c#

Tags: event-receivers, dropdown

I have an event reciever that fires when ever an item attachment is added.

```
 public override void ItemAttachmentAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAttachmentAdded(properties);
       }
```

[image]

The metadata should autocomplete depending on the items name.

Everything is working perfect exact for the comboboxes like the one displayed below (Sector).

I want to know how to change the selected value the combobox programatically.

Ex. i want to change the value to "FF - Fire Fighting".

Answer (score 0):

Set Column's `Default value` to 'FF - Fire Fighting'(your data).

- Go to *List/Libray Settings*
- Edit Column
- Set *Default valu*e what you want.

Set Default Value Programmatically:

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://dev.site.com"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList customDocumentLibrary = web.Lists["Program Documents"];
                MetadataDefaults columnDefaults = new MetadataDefaults(customDocumentLibrary);

                SPFolder testFolder = customDocumentLibrary.RootFolder.SubFolders["Programs"];

                columnDefaults.SetFieldDefault("/Program Documents/Programs/Academics", "Programs", "Academics");
                columnDefaults.Update();
            }

        }
```

Ref:

- [Setting default value for metadata column programmatically](http://sharepoint.aspcode.net/view/63539928672422258218768/setting-default-value-for-metadata-column-programmatically)
- [Set Default Column Values](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/07/19/how-to-set-default-column-values-on-a-folder-programmatically.aspx)
- [Setting default value for the column programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10551/setting-default-value-for-metadata-column-programmatically)